# How to pass more than 1 input into a Tensorflow Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I am stuck at passing in 3 inputs (placeholders with different shapes) into a neural network's hidden layer.

This is what I have so far:

```
with tf.name_scope("Final_Check"):
    # TODO: Is this the correct way to pass 3 inputs into the hidden layer?
    final_layer1 = tf.layers.dense([self.final_time_input, self.final_request_input, self.final_stream_input],
                                   500,
                                   activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                   name="final_hl1")
    final_layer2 = tf.layers.dense(final_layer1,
                                   500,
                                   activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                   name="final_h12")
    final_layer3 = tf.layers.dense(final_layer2,
                                   500,
                                   activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                   name="final_hl3")

    final_output = tf.layers.dense(final_layer3,
                                   500,
                                   activation=tf.nn.relu,
                                   name="final_output")
```

Placeholders:

1. self.final_time_input
2. self.final_request_input
3. self.final_stream_input

Hidden Layers: all the final_layer[1-3] and final_output

I have tried Googling for some sample code but unable to find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.layers.dense` expects tensor input. It is a list (`[self.final_time_input, self.final_request_input, self.final_stream_input]`) in your case. You need to concatenate them by using `tf.concat` such that

```
tf.concat([self.final_time_input, self.final_request_input, self.final_stream_input], axis=1)
```

Assuming that input tensors have a shape of `[batch_size, feature_size]` where `feature_size` can be different.

Comment: Is `tf.concat` the way how we pass more than 1 inputs(tf.placeholder) from input layer to hidden layer? Because the problem that I have in this case is that I want pass several pieces of information into the hidden layers, for example, the time period, Request type, etc into the hidden layer.

Comment: Yes, you can use `tf.concat`. If you want to apply different operations to different inputs, then you should first apply them and then concatenate the outputs.